# Cut in CLI doesn't work as expected - returns full lines every time

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm running MacOS Mojave and I'm trying to get a list of owners of files in given path. I'm trying to do it like this but it doesn't work.

```
$ ls -l /usr | cut -f3
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  971 root  wheel  31072 23 sty 20:05 bin
drwxr-xr-x  304 root  wheel   9728 23 sty 20:05 lib
drwxr-xr-x  248 root  wheel   7936 23 sty 20:05 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   16 root  wheel    512  3 lis 10:50 local
drwxr-xr-x  239 root  wheel   7648 23 sty 20:05 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   46 root  wheel   1472  3 lis 10:41 share
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel    160 21 wrz 06:06 standalone
```

Specifying delimiters seems to work but not for the TAB character (which should be default).

```
$ ls -l /usr | cut -f3 -d' '

971
304
248

239
```

I'm using ZSH with Oh my zsh and iTerm 2 if it matters.

Comment: Can you add some details about what you intend to do with the list of owners? Depending on this there might be better solutions than parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: Tab is, indeed, the default for `cut`, but the output of `ls` isn't tab-delimited; it just uses calculated numbers of space characters to produce tabular output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can squeeze the white spaces into a single white space in `ls` 's output then use `cut`.

```
ls -l /usr | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

but avoid parsing `ls` output. Here's an alternate solution.

```
stat -f'%Su' /usr/*
```

Comment: +1 for not parsing the output from ls — see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs,&c.

Comment: `stat` seems to be a good solution to my problem and lets me retrieve more info without all the hassle with extracting specific columns. Thanks!

Comment: That second link should be just http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 12):

`ls` doesn't use tabs, `cut` doesn't work with a variable number of delimeters between fields.

```
ls -l /usr | awk '{print $3}'
```

will work, or

```
ls -l /usr | awk 'NR > 1 {print $3}'
```

if you want to skip the first line (`total 0` in your example).